# Linq Method syntax for retrieving single nested child entity

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I wonder if I could get some help with the following. I'm retrieving set of data as follows using EF.

```
var booking = this.GetDbSet<Booking>().Include(c => c.BookingProducts.Select(d => d.Product.PrinterProducts.Select(e => e.ProductPrices))).Single(c => c.BookingId == bookingId)
```

Within a PrinterProduct there is a foreign key PrinterId for an additional entity Printer. With the Booking Entity I also have PrinterId also linked by foreign key to the additonal entity Printer.

What I'm hoping to do is retrieve only the PrinterProduct relating to the PrinterId held in the booking entity rather that all the PrinterProducts as in my code. I've tried to use Join but have tied myself in knots!

Grateful for any help!

**Edit:**

Object structure:

```
public class Booking
{
    public Guid BookingId { get; set; }
    public string BookingName { get; set; }
    public Printer Printer { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<BookingProduct> BookingProducts { get; set; }
}

public class BookingProduct
{
    public int BookingProductId { get; set; }
    public Booking Booking { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PrinterProduct> PrinterProducts { get; set; }
}

public class PrinterProduct
{
    public int PrinterProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public Printer Printer { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductPrice> ProductPrices { get; set; }
}

public class ProductPrice
{
    public int ProductPriceId { get; set; }
    public PrinterProduct PrinterProduct { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class Printer
{
    public int PrinterId { get; set; }
    public string PrinterName { get; set; }   
    public IEnumerable<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PrinterProduct> PrinterProducts { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the newly added class structures in your question, I hope I can clear it up now.

From what I see, `Bookings` and `Products` have a many-to-many relation (where `BookingProduct` is used as the connection). The same is true for `Product` and `Printer` (where `PrinterProduct` is used as the connection).
From what I understand, you are trying to get from a *singular `Booking` item* to a *singular `PrinterProduct`*. I don't see any efficient way to do this without introducing the possibility of inconsistency with your data. You're expecting some Lists to return you one result. If it's only one result, why is it a List in the first place?

- You have a single `Booking`. You take its `BookingProducts`. Now you have many items.
- You take the `Product` from each individual `BookingProduct`. If all `BookingProducts` have the same product, you're in luck and will only have a `List<Product>` with a single `Product` in it. However, there is nothing stopping the system from return many different products, so we are to assume that you now hold a `List` of several `Products`
- From each `Product` in the list, you now take all of its `PrinterProducts`. You now hold **many** `PrinterProducts` of **many** `Products`.

As you see, you end up with a whole list of items, not just the singular entity you're expecting.

`Bookings`, `Products` and `Printers` are all connected to eachother individually, like a triangle. I have seen scenarios where that is correct, but nine times out of ten, this is not what you want; and only leads to possible data inconsistency.
Look at it this way: Is it ever possible for the `Product` to have a `Printer` *other than the `Printer` that is already related to the `Booking`*? If not, then why would you have two relations? This only introduces the possibility that `Booking.Printer` is not the same as `PrinterProduct.Printer`.

Your relational model is set up to yield many results, but I think you expect a single result in some places. I would suggest taking another look at your data model because it does not reflect the types of operation you wish to perform on it. Change the many-to-many relations to one-to-many where applicable, and you should be able to traverse your data model in a more logical fashion, akin to the answer I provided in my previous answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer...In answer to your point about PrinterProducts being a list....within a Booking, Printer is nullable (apologies for not making this clear). When it is null then I would need to return the full list of PrinterProducts. It's only when Printer in Booking has a value that I only want the relevant PrinterProduct.

Comment: This operation is the sticking point at the mo but I can live with always bringing back a list of PrinterProducts and filtering the one I need when I need it based in the Printer in the Booking when it exists. At least you've confirmed the difficulty in what I was trying to achieve and saved me from wasting any more time. I'm grateful for the time you've given. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you've set up navigational properties, you can just browse to it:

```
var myBooking = ... //A single Booking, don't know how you retrieve it in your case.

var myPrinter = myBooking.Printer; //the Printer that is related to the Booking.

var myPrintproducts = myPrinter.PrintProducts; //The products that are related to the printer.
```

You don't need to keep nesting select statements, that only creates unnecessary confusion and overhead cost.
**Keep in mind that you need to do this while in scope of the db context.** Every time you try to access a property, EF will fill in the needed variables from the database. As long as there is an open db connection, it works.

**Edit**

If you really need to optimize this, you can use a Select statement. But you only need a single one. For example:

```
var myPrintproducts = db.Bookings.Single( x => x.ID == some_id_variable ).Select( x => x.Printer.PrintProducts);
```

But unless you have a very strict performance requirement, it seems better for code readability to just browse to it.

Comment: Which entity relates to which? If the PrintProducts has a Printer related, you should be able to request it that way.

Comment: Sorry, I should've included the Single call...amended now. I'm currently browsing through the navigation properties but the call brings back all the PrinterProducts where I only require a single one...I wondered if I could just make the call bring back the only one I need. Something like:  this.GetDbSet<Booking>().Include(c => c.BookingProducts.Select(d => d.Product.PrinterProducts.Single(f => f.PrinterId == c.PrinterId).Select(e => e.ProductPrices))).Single(c => c.BookingId == bookingId)

Comment: `d.Product.PrinterProducts.Single(f => f.PrinterId == c.PrinterId)` You are expecting a single PrinterProduct to be returned? I think you'll want to use a `Where` statement, this can return multiples. But if your Booking has a Printer, and your PrintProducts all have a Printer, why not just go through the printer like in my answer above?

Comment: yeah i want a single PrinterProduct rather than the multiple that are being returned. I can't go through the Printer in the booking because I need the PrinterProduct that is attached to the Product that is attached to each of the BookingProducts within the booking...make sense? ;-) Sounds like spaghetti to me! I can live with the fact all the PrinterProducts are returned and just browse to it as in your first answer...it just struck me that I could do it in SQL so it may be possible with Linq Method syntax,

Comment: I'd suggest adding this structure to your original question. If we know how your objects relate to eachother, this should make it better to understand. I'll take a look again then.

Comment: Hi Flater...done that now. Thanks for the suggestion and help.